# Выписывается в консоль намного больше обьектов чем я добавил в файл - Java

Tags: java

я в файл.ser додавляю три обьекта, но когда пытаюсь их вывести выводится те же три обьекта но очень много раз, почему так происходит?

```
        Student student01 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[0], daneImieNazwisko[1], daneOceny[0], daneOceny[1], daneOceny[2], daneOceny[3], daneOceny[4]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta1: \n");
        System.out.print(student01.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student01.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        Student student02 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[2], daneImieNazwisko[3], daneOceny[5], daneOceny[6], daneOceny[7], daneOceny[8], daneOceny[9]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta2: \n");
        System.out.print(student02.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student02.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        Student student03 = new Student(daneImieNazwisko[4], daneImieNazwisko[5], daneOceny[10], daneOceny[11], daneOceny[12], daneOceny[13], daneOceny[14]);
        System.out.print("\nDane studenta3: \n");
        System.out.print(student03.showImieNazwisko() + "\n");
        System.out.print(student03.showOceny());

        System.out.print("\n");

        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("wynikiStudenci.ser"));
            students.add(student01);
            students.add(student02);
            students.add(student03);
            for (Student student : students) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(student);
            }
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            System.out.print("Dane studentow zostaly zapisane do pliku \"wynikiStudenci.ser\"");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.print("Blad: " + exc);
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("wynikiStudenci.ser"));
            while (true) {
                try {
                    students.add((Student) objectInputStream.readObject());
                    for (Student student : students) {
                        System.out.print("\n" + student.showImieNazwisko() + "\n" + student.showOceny());
                    }
                } catch (EOFException exc) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            objectInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.print("Blad: " + exc);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы записываете в `ArrayList` экземпляры `Student` дважды. В первый раз при записи их в файл и второй раз при считывании их из файла. Итого у вас там 6 объектов `Student`.
Или используйте два разных `ArrayList` - один для записи в файл и другой для  чтения из файла или удалите объекты `Student` из списка `students` после записи в файл, например так:

```
students.removeAll(students);
```

Также там проблема в логике вывода объектов на консоль. Нужно вынести цикл `for` из цикла `while`